# OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer and normal Spritebatch renders a white box?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using Libgdx to render a TileMap as a background of my game. I might render some different layers later on.
Without the tilemap render and a single background picture it works correctly!
Something strange happens when i use the TiledRender just take a look at it:
[image: tiled scene with big white box in the upper left]

The two white areas are normally a touchpad and a character.

The touchpad and the character are rendered with:

```
@Override
   public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
      sprite.draw(batch);
   }
```

My Map where i render my TileMap looks like this:

```
public class Map extends Actor {
   private TiledMap map;
   private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer render;
   public int[][] mapArray = new int[Config.X_SIZE][Config.Y_SIZE];

   public Map(TiledMap map){
      this.map  = map;
      this.render = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map,(((float)Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_HEIGHT/Config.Y_SIZE)/(float)Config.TILE_SIZE));
      this.toBack();
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
      this.render.setView((OrthographicCamera) this.getStage().getCamera());
      render.render();
   }
}
```

any sugestions to fix the SpriteBatch problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of the Libgdx render helper objects assume they "own" the state in the OpenGL runtime, so  the output gets confused if you have two of them making changes to OpenGL at the same time.  In your case the `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer` has its own `SpriteBatch`, so you have two `SpriteBatch` (silently) fighting each other.

Try changing your `Map.render()` method to end the in-progress SpriteBatch before rendering the map (and then restart it afterwards):

```
@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
  batch.end();
  this.render.setView((OrthographicCamera) this.getStage().getCamera());
  render.render();
  batch.begin();
}
```

If that helps, you might look at setting up your tile map to "share" the same `SpriteBatch` as the rest of your code (as these are somewhat heavy objects).  That should be more efficient and should remove the need to end/start the `SpriteBatch`.

Comment: Awesome you are right. I just change the `.start()` to `.begin()` ;)

Comment: I love it. I struggled with this for a bit too and didn't realise that I had to render my maps separately from other items between batch.begin() and batch.end(). Doing what is suggested above really got me to understand the process. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where I was using a batch to first draw a tilemap, then my own textures. It drew white rectangles at exactly the right size and position as the texture.

```
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    mapRenderer.render();
    GameObjectSystem.inst().render(RenderLayer.floor, batch);
    GameObjectSystem.inst().render(RenderLayer.ground, batch);
    batch.end();
```

Ending the batch after drawing the tilemap and restarting it fixed the problem.

```
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    mapRenderer.render();
    batch.end();

    batch.begin();
    GameObjectSystem.inst().render(RenderLayer.floor, batch);
    GameObjectSystem.inst().render(RenderLayer.ground, batch);
    batch.end();
```