# libgdx camera.position.set causes tearing

Tags: java, libgdx

I am working with libgdx and my game renders perfectly fine if I don't try to set the camera's position. But if I just add this one line of code: camera.position.set(0f,0f,0f), it causes white lines to show on all my sprites.

Before:
[image]

After adding one line of code: camera.postion.set(0f,0f,0f)
[image]

These images are random maps so the layouts are different. The only thing that changes are the white lines. The camera does go to the location (0,0,0).
What could be causing this? It's basically adding 1 white pixel to the top of my sprites. I have a 512x512 tile sheet with the 64x64 tiles in it. Here is the relevant code

Inside of a Screen class:

```
@Override
public void show() 
{
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, h);

    this.camera.setToOrtho(true, w, h);
    this.stage.setCamera(this.camera);
    camera.update();

    this.input = new InputHandler(this.camera);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this.input);

    dungeon = new Dungeon(DungeonGenerator.generateDungeonMap());

    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(dungeon);

    this.player = new Player(dungeon);
    this.stage.addActor(this.player);

    camera.position.set(0f, 0f, 0f);

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) 
{

       Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
       Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();

    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, "FPS: " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(), 10, 20); 
    font.draw(batch, "camera: " + camera.position, 10, 50); 
    font.draw(batch, "Stage:" + this.stage.getCamera().position, 10, 80);
    batch.end();

    //update and render stage actors
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();



}
```

Comment: This might apply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883120/orthogonaltiledmaprenderer-and-normal-spritebatch-renders-a-white-box

Comment: Thanks. I just read it. I am trying that solution right now, but I don't think it is the same problem

Comment: I tried different things using batch.begin() and batch.end() like the solution in the link but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was caused from my spritesheet having a white background. After making some changes to my spritesheet, I must have exported the sheet without hiding my white background. I just added the alpha background back to the spritesheet and it works fine again.